# Intercepting user input from subdialog VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on file saving, the code for saving is following:

```
Dim workbookName As Variant

workbookName = wb.Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
        fileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Worksheet (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
If workbookName <> False Then
    If Not Dir(workbookName) <> "" Then
        wb.SaveAs Filename:=workbookName
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else 
            wb.SaveAs Filename:=workbookName, _
                      AccessMode:=xlExclusive, _
                      FileFormat:=xlWorkbook, _
                      ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
        End If
    End If
End If
wb.Close (True)
```

This allows to choose file location and file name. It also partially handles error when file name is being used by other file (1004). In case when file already exists `GetSaveAsFilename` displays dialog that asks whether to replace or not.

Dialog displayed by `GetSaveAsFilename` looks like this:
[image: Replace confirmation dialog]

That causes 2 problems:

- **replaced file becomes corrupted** (the code is invoked from user form and no other code is executed after wb.Close (True))
- **the dialog is created by `GetSaveAsFilename` so I cannot handle user input in code**

Any idea what could cause file to become corrupted? Is there a way to handle that user clicked "No"?

Comment: you have duplicate  **xlsx** on this part `(*.xlsx), *.xlsx")`

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Your code does nothing between `On Error Resume Next` and checking for error = 1004.  What would have triggered that error?

Comment: FYI `GetSaveAsFilename` does not trigger the dialog you show - that is raised when saving the workbook over an existing file of the same name.